# If input doesn't have a value function doesnt triggger

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I am creating a website and I'm wondering how I create something where when a user enters an input and no value is submitted, instead of a function called `togglePopup()` occurring a function called `togglePopup2()` will occur.  How can I accomplish this? Here is my current code:

```
<form  autocomplete="off" >
            <input style="border: 2px solid #222; border-radius: 6px;" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" maxlength="10"><br><br><br>
            <input style="border: none; border-radius: 6px; color: ivory; text-shadow: 0px 10px 20px; #222;background: dodgerblue; padding: 15px; font-size: 15px;" value="Submit environment name" type="button"  onclick="togglePopup()">
          </form><script>
              var x;
document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  x = document.querySelector('input').value;
})
          </script>
```

Currently a function called `togglePopup()` occurs when the button is clicked submitting the input. How can I make it so the function only occurs when there is text in the input and if nothing is submitted, an alternate function will occur called `togglePopup2()` will occur. How can this be done?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
   const f = this.value.trim() === '' ? togglePopup2 : togglePopup; f();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const togglePopup = ()=>{
  document.querySelector('button').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
const togglePopup2 = ()=>{
  document.querySelector('button').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.querySelector('input').value.trim() === "");
  if(document.querySelector('input').value.trim() === ""){
    togglePopup2();
  } else {
    togglePopup();
  }
};
```

```css
input{
  border: 2px solid #222;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

button{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: ivory;
  text-shadow: 0px 10px 20px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<form  autocomplete="off" action="#" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" maxlength="10">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit environment name</button>
  </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var x;
 document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].addEventListener("click", () => {
   x = document.getElementById('lname').value;
   if (x != '') {
     togglePopup()
   } else {
     togglePopup2()
   }
 })

 function togglePopup() {
   console.log('togglePopup');
 }

 function togglePopup2() {
   console.log('togglePopup2');
 }
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  <input style="border: 2px solid #222; border-radius: 6px;" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" maxlength="10"><br><br><br>
  <input style="border: none; border-radius: 6px; color: ivory; text-shadow: 0px 10px 20px; #222;background: dodgerblue; padding: 15px; font-size: 15px;" value="Submit environment name" type="button">
</form>
```